# Nlog structured logging not working for classes

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

I have following code:

```cs
var logger = LogManager.Setup().LoadConfigurationFromAppSettings().GetCurrentClassLogger();
logger.Info("Application starting");

var a = new A() { B = 5, C = "Test123" };
var b = new { B = a.B, C = a.C};

logger.Info("Test: {@value1}", a); // Outputs "Test: A" (Writes namespace, not values)
logger.Info("Test: {@value1}", b); // Outputs "Test: {"a":5, "c":"Sasadasd"}" (Nice)

class A 
{
  public int B;
  public string C;
}
```

Instead of structured logging for classes and converting them to json, I got .ToString() called on object instead. I just don't understand what should I do. I searched the entire internet for like 8 hours, and it seems nobody have the same issue as me. Pls help :(

My config file:

```json
"NLog": {
    "throwConfigExceptions": true,
    "variables": {
      "solution": "A",
      "project": "A.A"
    },
    "targets": {
      "c": {
        "type": "ColoredConsole",
        "layout": "${longdate} ${message}"
      }
    },
    "rules": [
      {
        "logger": "Microsoft.*",
        "maxLevel": "Info",
        "final": true
      },
      {
        "logger": "*",
        "maxLevel": "Warn",
        "writeTo": "c"
      },
      {
        "logger": "*",
        "minLevel": "Error",
        "writeTo": "c"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: NLog JsonSerializer does not recognize fields, but only properties. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging#customize-object-reflection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need properties for Nlog to show the json value :
if you use this class it will work :

```
public class A 
{
  public int B { get; set; }
  public string C { get;set; } 
}
```

here is the code example with Nlog : https://dotnetfiddle.net/8zRtvO